# There is no directive with “exportAs” set to “ngForm” - Yes, I've seen the other posts

Tags: angular, forms, import

Yes, I know this question has been posted a hundred times. I have tried all the other solutions I could find.

I have tried importing FormsModule in app.module.ts, in app.component.ts, and in buy.component.ts. I have tried importing it in app and component, in app and buy, and in all three. I have tried npm update. I have tried moving the form itself into app.component.html. I have tried importing ReactiveFormsModule instead, and I have tried importing both FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule. Nothing is working, and it's driving me nuts.

Here is app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './/app-routing.module';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { BuyComponent } from './buy/buy.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    BuyComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  hover1;
  hover2;
}
```

buy.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-buy',
  templateUrl: './buy.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./buy.component.css']
})
export class BuyComponent implements OnInit {
  formBuy: Object = {
    newOnly: false,
    make: [],
    model: [],
    transmission: [],
    year: {
      yearFrom: 0,
      yearTo: 0
    },
    price: {
      priceFrom: 0,
      priceTo: 0
    },
    mileage: {
      mileageFrom: 0,
      mileageTo: 0
    },
    location: {
      locationDistance: 0,
      locationZipcode: 0
    }
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

buy.component.html:

```
<div class="container-fluid element-margin-top">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1" style="background-color: gold;">
      <form #f="NgModel" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And package.json:

```
{
  "name": "salesite",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "ng-bootstrap-dropdown": "^1.0.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.7",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.108",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
<form #f="NgModel" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
```

To:

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.value)">
```

With `#f="ngForm"` you create a template variable - `f` that is being assigned to your FormGroup of this form, so `form.value` is also not valid as there are no variables that points to `form`

Comment: Ah! You're my hero, thank you!! That makes sense now haha

Comment: Yeah it takes some time to get used to it